# listen "disconnect" click event (metamask wallet ui) with multiple accounts in metamask

Tags: metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I'm using metamask in my vue app. User flow is similar to [this docs section](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/create-dapp.html#basic-action-part-1).
User has several accounts in wallet and the problem is when user clicking a "disconnect" button in metamask UI. Metamask connects another user account and we have this:
[image]

questionable behavior, as for me?